# Rcpp - Exposing a C++ function that contains pointers to R

Tags: rcpp, rcpp11

I am using Rcpp to create a package in R that leverages C++ code. I have read all of the Rcpp vignettes, but I haven't been able to find a solution to the following problem.

One of the `C++` classes I'm trying to use contains a pointer. I am exposing the class using a module. When I try to install the package in R, I get the following error.

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '*' token.field("*w", &ffm_model::*w)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Code for Class Containing Pointer**

```
typedef float ffm_float;
typedef int ffm_int;

class ffm_model {
  public:
    ffm_int n; // number of features
    ffm_int m; // number of fields
    ffm_int k; // number of latent factors
    ffm_float *w = nullptr;
    bool normalization;
    ~ffm_model();
};
```

**Code for Corresponding RCPP Module**

```
RCPP_MODULE(ffmModelMod){
  using namespace Rcpp;

  //Expose class as ffm_model on the r side
  class_<ffm_model>( "ffm_model")

    .field("n", &ffm_model::n)
    .field("m", &ffm_model::m)
    .field("k", &ffm_model::k)
    .field("*w", &ffm_model::*w)
    .field("normalization", &ffm_model::normalization)
    .method("~ffm_model",&ffm_model::~ffm_model)
    ;
}
```

Comment: `float*` or `double*` is NOT a type that can be mapped automatically to a `SEXP`, which is what the compiler tells you with the error.  You also cannot declare the dtor method.  Looks into `Rcpp::XPtr` to wrap a pointer,

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. I will look into Rcpp::XPtr. As for the dtor method... Is this something that can be solved with Rcpp::XPtr as well?

Comment: You can also stay with modules, but you still need `XPtr` on the interface.  And you should not need an explicit dtor.

Comment: I think I will stick with modules and then use XPtr on the interface. What documentation do you recommend I read to get me started? I have already gone through the Rcpp "extending" and "modules" vignettes, but I still don't fully understand how to integrate XPtr with modules.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and as Dirk mentions, it is due to types that cannot be mapped automatically, such as `float*`.

The following workaround works for me:

1. Do not expose the fields with problematic types to R.
2. Instead, expose `get()` and `set()` functions to the fields above.

Here is an example, in which both the (unproblematic) `value` field and the (problematic) `child` field (a pointer to an object of the same class) are hidden:

**Class**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class node
{
public:
    double value; // Voluntarily hidden from R
    node* child; // Must be hidden from R

    // Exposed functions
    void setVal(double value);
    double getVal();

    node* createNode(double value); // return pointer to a node
    node* createChild(double value); // set child
    node* getChild();

};
```

**Methods**

```
void node::setVal(double value){
    this->value = value;
}
double node::getVal(){
    return this->value;
} 
node* node::createNode(double value){
    node* n = new node;
    n->value = value;
    return n;
}
node* node::createChild(double value){
    this->child = createNode(value);
    return child;
}
node* node::getChild(){
    return this->child;
}
```

**RCPP Module**

```
RCPP_MODULE(gbtree_module){
    using namespace Rcpp;
    class_<node>("node")
        .constructor()
      .method("setVal", &node::setVal)
      .method("getVal", &node::getVal)
      .method("createNode", &node::createNode)
      .method("createChild", &node::createChild)
      .method("getChild", &node::getChild)
    ;
}
```

**Usage in R**

```
n <- new(node)
n$setVal(2)
n$getVal()
n2 <- n$createNode(1) # unrelated node
n3 <- n$createChild(3) #child node
n$getChild() #pointer to child node
n3
```